# "Service Spreadsheets failed" error when calling openById method in a standalone script project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying to access spreadsheets from a standalone google script, but keep getting the following error message:

> Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id abcdefg_example_id. (Code:25:33)

```
function doSomething() {
  var theSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abcdefg_example_id");
  if(theSheet == null){
    Logger.log("NO SPREADSHEET");
  } else {
    Logger.log("SPREADSHEET REEE");
  }
  Logger.log(theSheet.getName());
}
```

How do I access a spreadsheet by ID from a standalone google script?

Also, I've tried running the same code within a container bound script and it won't work when trying to open a different spreadsheet. Same error message. My goal is basically to access and modify other spreadsheets ideally from a standalone script but I don't mind if it has to be done another way.

---

I tried the same code on my PC using personal files and it works. I'm trying to get this code to work on a work computer but it runs into the issue above. I'm guessing maybe it's an authorization problem or perhaps an administrator restriction of some sort. Any ideas?

Comment: That should do it.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. How are you getting the spreadsheet id?

Comment: CNM, hm, if you are still around, could you clarify if at work you use a GSuite account and a [Shared Drive](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7212025?hl=en)?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked if the spreadsheet you're trying to "openById" is in a Google Doc format(has been converted when uploaded to Gdrive)? if it is not, google app script will throw this error.

Comment: Thank you for this! I was facing the same issue where i wanted to upload files from one drive to other drive just for the sake of changing the ownership. I downloaded the files from one drive and uploaded it to other and in this process, the files got changed from Googlesheets to .xlsx which was why the appscript APIs were failing. I then solved this by changing ownership from drive directly. But knowing the root cause of the issue was a huge relief!

Answer (score 1):

I just did this:

```
function getDataFromAnotherSpreadsheet() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid");
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();
  const vs=rg.getValues();
  let html="";
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    html+=r.join(',') + '<br />';
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Results")
}
```

My Output:

```
COL12,A1,COL10,B1,COL8,C1,COL6,D1,COL4,E1,COL2
133,1,109,1,85,1,61,1,37,1,13
134,2,110,2,86,2,62,2,38,2,14
135,3,111,3,87,3,63,3,39,3,15
136,4,112,4,88,4,64,4,40,4,16
137,5,113,5,89,5,65,5,41,5,17
138,6,114,6,90,6,66,6,42,6,18
139,7,115,7,91,7,67,7,43,7,19
140,8,116,8,92,8,68,8,44,8,20
141,9,117,9,93,9,69,9,45,9,21
.....
```

Getting ID: (animation)

[image]

Comment: Hello Cooper. Thanks for chiming in. Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem although it did help me narrow in on the issue. I tried my same code on my personal computer and everything worked. I'm originally working on a work computer though, so I'm guessing maybe its an authorization issue or administrator setting.

Comment: Yes.  The admin probably is not allowing that kind of access for most users.  You can probably ask them to grant you that access for certain folders.